# Play multiple videos perfectly synchron in html5 / js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a standard html 5 frontend, javascript backend setup. I need to play 8 videos synchronically.

Problem is, it is a music website, so the videos have to play PERFECTLY synchron.
I have 8 videoplayer and I await the **canplaythrough** event for every video, then loop over the player (items) to start the videos with **item.play()**:

```
if(videosStillBuffering == 0){
    if(!videosHavePlayed){
        videosHavePlayed = true;
        videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
    item.currentTime = 0;
 });
    }
     videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
    item.play();
 });
```

But the videos don't play EXACTLY at the same time, the timing is of by a little less than half a second or so. That's still too much. Is there a way to explain to the website, that the videos have to play together, or is there a way to at least reduce the difference between th evideos further? Like, give the videos the play command asynchronically?

Here's the js source:

```
const videoContainerCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('video-container');
const videoContainerArray = [...videoContainerCollection];
const playPauseButton = document.getElementById('playPause');

var shouldPlay = false;
var playPauseButtonSaysPlay = true;
var videosHavePlayed = false;

playPauseButton
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
       if(playPauseButtonSaysPlay){
             shouldPlay = true;
                 playIfBuffered();
       } else {
             shouldPlay = false;
             pause();
                 playPauseButton.className = playPauseButton.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)blue(?!\S)/g , 'green' );
                 playPauseButton.innerHTML = "Play";
                 playPauseButtonSaysPlay = true;
         }
}, true);

videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (event) => {
        console.log("canplaythrough " );
        if(shouldPlay){
             playIfBuffered();
        }
});
});

videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('waiting', (event) => {
            console.log("waiting " );
        if(shouldPlay){
            playIfBuffered();
     }
});
});

function checkReady() {
    var countReady = 0;
    videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
        if ( item.readyState >= 3 ) {   // it's loaded
            countReady++;
        }
    });
    return countReady;
}

function playIfBuffered() {
    const videosStillBuffering = videoContainerArray.length - checkReady()
    if(videosStillBuffering == 0){
        if(!videosHavePlayed){
            videosHavePlayed = true;
            videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
        item.currentTime = 0;
     });
        }
         videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
        item.play();
     });
         playPauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
         playPauseButton.className = playPauseButton.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)green(?!\S)/g , 'blue' );
         playPauseButtonSaysPlay = false;
    } else {
        pause();
        playPauseButton.className = playPauseButton.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)green(?!\S)/g , 'blue' );
        playPauseButton.innerHTML = videosStillBuffering + " of " + videoContainerArray.length + " vidoes are buffering. Please Wait.";
    }
}

function pause() {
    videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
           item.pause();
    });
}

document.getElementById('stop')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
        shouldPlay = false;
        playPauseButtonSaysPlay = true;
        playPauseButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        playPauseButton.className = playPauseButton.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)blue(?!\S)/g , 'green' );
        videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
            item.pause();
            item.currentTime = 2;
     });
     videosHavePlayed = false;
    }, false);

videoContainerArray.forEach(toggleMute);
function toggleMute(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (item.muted === true) {
      item.muted = false;
      item.style.opacity = "1";
      item.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=100)'; // IE fallback
    }
    else if (item.muted === false) {
      item.muted = true;
      item.style.opacity = "0.5";
      item.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=50)'; // IE fallback
    }
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to check all videos every 500ms if the current time of the video is more than 0.1 sec from the time of the first video. If so, set the current time of the video to the current time of the first video:

```
setInterval(
    function(){
          videoContainerArray.forEach(function(item) {
          var currentTime = videoContainerArray[0].currentTime;
          var videoTime = item.currentTime;
              if (Math.abs(currentTime - videoTime) > 0.1) {
                  item.currentTime = currentTime;
              }
     });        
}, 500);
```

I actually think the synchronicity of the videos wasn't the problem in our case, one of the videos was probably just cut incorrectly :(